# Trapdoor committement using ring lattices involving three parties

Tags: lattice-crypto, ring-lwe, trapdoor

Assume there are three parties say A, B, C.

1. A commits to a message $m$ say $c(m)$ and sends tuple $(m,c(m))$ to B.
2. B has to prove to C that he possesses commitment $c(m)$. There is no interaction between A and C. But B should not cheat by sending commitment to some other message $m^\prime$.

I guess for this we need A to generate $c(m)$ using his own trapdoor and later C can verify it is generated by A itself. Is it possible to achieve this using lattice based hard problems like $RSIS$ or $RLWE$.

Or is there any other way to achieve this using $RSIS$ or $RLWE$. ?

Comment: If there is no communication between $A$ and $C$, then from $C$'s perspective they are simply communicating with $B$ (or perhaps $B^A$, $B$ with oracle access to $A$). In this setting there are simple solutions, i.e. $B$ and $C$ doing a key exchange and then using standard tools. In what ways would your desired solution look different than this simplistic one?

Comment: thanks for the reply, your comments brought some clarity to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is just a digital signature scheme. $A$ should generate a private signing key and a public verification key for your signature scheme of choice. The then create a signature for the message $m$ and which you are calling the commitment $c(m)$. $B$ can then pass on the $c(m)$ to $C$ who can confirm that is is signed by $A$, but $B$ cannot produce signatures for other messages that verify using $A$'s verification key.

There are several lattice-based signature schemes though they are all quite tricky to parameterise and implement securely. The NIST competition has advanced the lattice-based signatures [FALCON](https://falcon-sign.info) and [Crystals DILITHIUM](https://pq-crystals.org/dilithium/) to the final round.

Comment: thanks for the answer.